# Getting an NSURLRequest for use in UIImageView setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, afnetworking-2

This question assumes AFNetworking 2.0.

I have an AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, and I have a UIImageView. My URL for the image in question requires authentication and several parameters.

With AFNetworking 1.x I had an AFHTTPClient that I could use to get a NSURLRequest from and then pass that into the UIImageView setImageWithURLRequest:... method. I can't find anything in the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager that returns an NSURLRequest.

Am I just blind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to have the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager make a NSURLRequest for me. However, the requestSerializer will make one so I am using that. The only problem is that the requestSerializer doesn't know about the baseURL, so I have to pull that out of the operation manager first.

```
NSString* fullPath = [self.HTTPRequestOperationManager.baseURL.absoluteString stringByAppendingString: path];
NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [self.HTTPRequestOperationManager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod: @"GET" URLString: fullPath parameters: parameters error: &error];
```

I'll have to suggest this as a feature request. I should not have to pull one piece of information out the a RequestOperationManager only to send it to another piece of the same RequestOperationManager.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into AFURLSessionManager? Looks like it supports downloading and you set the NSURLRequest yourself so you could set the params and all that:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#afurlsessionmanager

Comment: I see there are several methods in a session manager that *accept* a NSURLRequest. I don't see any methods that *create* an NSURLRequest which is what I need to pass to UIImageView. Nor are there any such methods, that I can find, in the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, which is the class I am using.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have a URL and parameters. Can't you create the NSURLRequest and pass it through?

Comment: The AFHTTPRequestOperationManager has the base URL and account credentials already in it and all of those items need to be included in the NSURLRequest. Yes, I guess I could make an NSURLRequest from scratch, but I expected to be able to have the HTTPROM build it for me to keep DRY. Maybe this is a missing feature?